# подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать,что бы выводило тик так

Tags: javascript

```js
var timerId = setTimeout(function tick() {
  console.log("Tик");
  timerId = setTimeout(tick, 1000);
}, 3000);

var timerId2 = setTimeout(function tack() {
  console.log("Taк");
  timerId2 = setTimeout(tack, 2000);
}, 4000);
```

Comment: @anton-shchyrov, спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Заменить в первой функции 1000 на 2000

```js
var timerId = setTimeout(function () {
  console.log("Tик");
  timerId = setTimeout(tick, 2000);
}, 3000);

var timerId2 = setTimeout(function () {
  console.log("Taк");
  timerId2 = setTimeout(tack, 2000);
}, 4000);
```

Или задать единый интервал со счетчиком состояния

```js
var tick = true;

var timerId = setInterval(function() {
  if (tick)
    console.log("Tик");
  else
    console.log("Tак");
  tick = !tick;
}, 1000);
```